# Convert 12hr date/time string to 24hr datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time

Like other questions asked here, im looking to do a simple conversion of time formats. I've found answers on how to do this in Perl, but not in Python.

I have a string like so:

```
on Jun 03, 02010 at 10:22PM
```

and I'd like to convert it to a datetime object like this:

```
Thu, 03 Jun 2010 22:22:00 -0000
```

I have sliced up my input like so:

```
date = str(comment.div.contents[5].contents)
month = date[6:9]
day   = date[10:12]
year  = date[15:19]
time  = date[23:30]
```

which sets me up with some nice variables I can throw back into datetime but before I so, I must convert the time. Should I divide up `time` in the example above and calculate the `hh` and `{AM|PM}` separately?

Comment: I guess you'll have to disregard the lack of clarity in the system itself - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_meridiem#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers. I gave the point to ~ubuntu but ablerman and Muhammad Alkarouri were also equally helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
import datetime as dt
import dateutil.parser as dparser

date_str='on Jun 03, 02010 at 10:22PM'
date=dparser.parse(date_str)
print(date)
# 2010-06-03 22:22:00
print(date.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'))
# Thu, 03 Jun 2010 22:22:00
```

If you can somehow strip out the pesky 'on' and change 02010 to 2010, in `date_str` then you could use `dt.datetime.strptime`:

```
date_str='Jun 03, 2010 at 22:22PM'
date=dt.datetime.strptime(date_str,'%b %d, %Y at %H:%M%p')
print(date)
# 2010-06-03 22:22:00
```

Or, as [Muhammad Alkarouri points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453702/convert-12hr-date-time-string-to-24hr-datetime/3453745#3453745), if `date_str`s always start with `on` and use a four-digit year prefixed by zero, then you could use

```
date_str='on Jun 03, 02010 at 22:22PM'
date=dt.datetime.strptime(date_str,'on %b %d, 0%Y at %H:%M%p')
print(date)
# 2010-06-03 22:22:00
```

Python's `strftime` and `strptime` use your machine's C functions of the same name. So check your local man page for what format codes are available for your machine. For a general list of format codes (which may be available) see https://www.php.net/strftime.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably better of using the standard library, namely [time.strptime](http://effbot.org/librarybook/time.htm).

In particular, the time you mentioned can be converted to a time.struct_time like so

```
In [9]: time.strptime("on Jun 03, 02010 at 10:22PM", "on %b %d, 0%Y at %I:%M%p") 

Out[9]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=3, tm_hour=22, tm_min=22, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=154, tm_isdst=-1) #store in variable t
```

Now that we have the `struct_time` in `t` we can do

```
In [14]: time.strftime('%a, %d %b %H:%M:%S %z', t)

Out[14]: 'Thu, 03 Jun 22:22:00 '
```

Note that the zone information you required in `"Thu, 03 Jun 22:22:00 -0000"` (the `-0000` bit) is not provided by the first format, therefore it won't appear in the result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty lazy, so I'd probably use strptime and strftime:

```
date = strptime(dateString, 'on %b %d, %Y at %I:%M%p')
date.strftime('%a, %d %b %H:%M:%S %z')
```